# How to create a web-project with gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

We can create an empty web-project with maven just generate it from the archetype like

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong 
    -DartifactId=CounterWebApp 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Is there something similat in gradle? I know we can create gradle build script and `apply plugin: 'war'` but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently project structure generation is supported on a very basic level. See [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html) for more details. So the answer is: no, it's not possible right now. You need to create the structure on your own.