# How to create a project structure with Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to figure how if it's possible to have a default project tree with Gradle.
According to this answer it seems it's not available out of the box:

[How to create a web-project with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592253/how-to-create-a-web-project-with-gradle)

However being the answer a bit dated, I hope some more options exists.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

gradle init --type java-library